# Makefile do not regenerate main target after delete it

Tags: makefile

I learning to write makefile. I meet a problem today. My makefile makes the main target successfully. Then I delete the main target and run the "make" command again. But the makefile did not make the main target, just show "make: `main.o' is up to date". I don't know why. Here is my makefile and folder structure:

```
CXX := g++          
FLAGS := -std=c++11                                                                                                                       

INCLUDE_DIR := $(shell find . -type d)
SOURCE_DIR := $(INCLUDE_DIR)

SOURCE_FILE := $(foreach dir, $(SOURCE_DIR), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))

OBJECT_FILE := $(SOURCE_FILE:%.cpp=%.o)

-include $(OBJECT_FILE:%.o=%.d)

TARGET := app       

all: $(TARGET)      

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT_FILE)
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECT_FILE)

$(OBJECT_FILE): %.o: %.cpp | $(SOURCE_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.d)


./-----main.cpp
|---test
    |---func.h
    |---func.cpp
```

Comment: You should post the command lines with their outputs.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Why gnu-make did not update the main target itself? Gun-make did not check the main target if need to update? And I don't want to post the command line with their outputs, is there any way let gun-make generate the main target again if not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you choose a specific target to be built on the command line (via `make <target>`), make will always choose the first target it sees in the makefile as the default target to be built

Consider these lines in your makefile:

```
-include $(OBJECT_FILE:%.o=%.d)

TARGET := app

all: $(TARGET)
```

When nothing is built, there are no `.d` files so the `-include` doesn't include anything.  Then make finds the target `all` and uses that as the default.

The second time through the makefile, there *are* `.d` files so the `-include` command includes them.  Those files define some targets, the first of which is `main.o`, and so now that is the first target and built by default.

You should move your `-include` down to the *end* of the makefile and ensure that the `all` target is always the first one built.

Just as an aside, I don't know if it's an artifact of your cut and paste into SO, but many of your lines have extra whitespace at the end.  You should be aware that extra whitespace at the end of lines *IS SIGNIFICANT* in makefiles, in many places.  I highly recommend using an editor that will allow you to visualize whitespace and/or automatically strip extra whitespace at the end of lines.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for tell me the reason and your advice.